# Writing IO at max_sectors_kb

Tags: linux, io, nvme

on Linux (using 5.9) if my NVMe disk has a `max_sectors_kb == 2048` but `logical_block_size == 512`, does that still mean that if i submit a write of 2048KB that either...

1. the entire operation will fail if the drive's kernel write queue is saturated (`nr_requests == 256`)

or

2. the entire 2048KB write will be written and never less than 2048KB?

I'm using io_uring and `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Can you clarify question 2 - are you asking about atomicity even in the face of power loss?

Answer (score 0):

1. `io_uring` has a queue of its own and you can set its `entries` in [`io_uring_setup(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/liburing-dev/io_uring_setup.2.en.html) to a number larger than 256. Further the [submission and completion queues are separate from the queues of in-flight requests](https://lwn.net/Articles/812021/) so you would have to saturate `entries` AND `nr_requests`.
2. Looks like someone asked Jens this over on https://twitter.com/victorxstewart/status/1338303336370593792 :

> **Victor Stewart** @victorxstewart
>
> @axboe if you only submit file IO of size hw_sector_kb, using O_DIRECT, with the fixed ops, is it still possible to get short reads or writes? or for batches to complete out of order?
>
> **Jens Axboe** @axboe Replying to @victorxstewart
>
> Short generally shouldn’t happen, out or order completions can (and will) always happen.

However you need to clarify your question. Are you actually asking "is O_DIRECT atomic even in the face of power failure?" (i.e. is all of a given I/O is written and if not does the area being written remain exactly as all old data)?

In the io-uring mailing list thread [[PATCH v3 RESEND] iomap: set REQ_NOWAIT according to IOCB_NOWAIT in Direct IO](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-fsdevel/a0760c52-cdd7-eb66-27dc-27582c2db825@linux.alibaba.com/T/#m078f7db7fc378faa7cd1272b8dfacb08550b7163) there is a warning that an initial filesystem I/Os can be split apart and be sent down separately (and worse separately fail) if certain other options are set.

It's probably best to ask more directly over on the io_uring mailing list - http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#io-uring .